# ng-show stops works with ng-animate

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show

I'm starting to play with AngularJS and I trying to make a tabbed with a simple animation with `ng-show` and `ng-animate`. You can see the simplified code here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1BYv2EgUWAudTlAAHFjl?p=preview).

When I try it without the `ng-animate` directive it works fine changing between panels (without animations of course) but when I try to use animations the `ng-show` directive only works the first time.